# Path conflict in Ocelot routing configuration

Tags: .net-core, microservices, url-routing, service-discovery, ocelot

How would you set re-reoute following two set of similar routes to different machines. Please advise.

**Problem/Question:** The conflicting situation is between `/customers/1` & `/customers/1/products` where each one is going to a different machine.

### - machine name: `customer`

```
GET /customers
GET /customers/1
POST /customers
PUT /customers1
DELETE /customers/1
```

### - machine name: `customerproduct`

```
GET /customers/1/products
PUT /customers/1/products
```

### ocelot.json

```
 {
  "ReRoutes": [

    {  
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/customers/{id}", 
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "customer",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/customers/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" ]
    },

    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/customers/{id}/products",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "customerproduct",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/customers/{id}/products",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Put" ]
    }

  ],

  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:80"
  }

}
```

Comment: Why does this not work? What error do you get?

Comment: the problem was `/customers/{id}` was getting intercepted for both `/customers/1` and `/customers/1/product1`

Comment: solved by changing the order, moved up the most specific route to generalized route.

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer or should I do it :)

Comment: I've done it. Hope that's OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an answer based on the OP's own solution in the comments.

The reason this was not working is because of order of evaluation. Ocelot will evaluate paths in the order they are specified, unless the *priority* property is specified on the routes (see docs https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/routing.html#priority)

So the in the following routing config:

```
{
   "ReRoutes":[
      {
         "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/customers/{id}", // <-- will be evaluated first
         ...
      },
      {
         "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/customers/{id}/products",
         ...
      },
      ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

the first path will be evaluated and Ocelot will match to this path even if the upstream call specifies the /products sub-path.

To fix this, **either** change the ordering so that the more specific path is evaluated first:

```
{
   "ReRoutes":[
      {
         "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/customers/{id}/products", // <-- will be evaluated first
         ...
      },
      {
         "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/customers/{id}",
         ...
      },
      ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

**or** use the priority property, with the priority being used to indicate the desired order of evaluation:

```
{
   "ReRoutes":[
      {
         "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/customers/{id}",
         "Priority": 0, 
         ...
      },
      {
         "UpstreamPathTemplate":"/customers/{id}/products", // <-- will be evaluated first
         "Priority": 1, 
         ...
      },
      ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the priority example.

Comment: What about situation

/api/home/{everything}

/api/{everything}

For me the second route matches always regardless of the order that I have in the configuration or the priority I assign.

Comment: @milorad - this is why I try to avoid using {everything} route in Ocelot